# Comparison of predictors in multinomial logit

Tags: importance, multinomial-logit, relative-risk

I have been reading up on ways to understand variable importance in multinomial logistic so as to compare the predictors. My goal is to understand whether predictor A or B is playing a more significant role in the selection of 3 options.

With 2 binary predictors of the same type and an outcome variable with 3 classes (Selection of 1, 2 or 3), it does not look like there is widespread agreement on comparing which predictor is most important in the selection (vs the reference). If there is, I apologize, as I have missed it in searching the forum.

If the reference for Selection = 1, and we have the relative risk ratios below...

Selection 2: Predictor A: 1.25 ; Predictor B: 1.1

Selection 3: Predictor A: 0.5  ; Predictor B: 1.5

I (think I) understand what the relative risk ratio means for one Predictor vs. the 2 options for Selection, but what I do not understand is if its safe/ allowable/ okay to say that Predictor B has a GREATER role/ is more likely/ is more powerful/ is more likely to drive toward Selection=3 (1.5) (vs. the reference) than Predictor A does in driving toward Selection = 2 (1.25) (vs. the reference).

Are comparisons of risk ratios across predictors okay, or am I completely off? I also read and saw that some measures of variable importance suggest summing up the absolute values of the coefficients (not the risk ratios, as I am suggesting above), which does effectively compare predictors, but that thread sort of ends there. Because of that, I was thinking this is allowable, and thus have ended up at the question above (trying to "quantify" that relationship).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Would recommend considering the use of dominance analysis - a topic that is covered at length in [Luchman (2014](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/1094428114544509)).

Overall, the dominance analysis attempts to determine how much of a pseudo-$R^2$ is attributable to each predictive factor in the model through an all subsets regression including and omitting each predictor to obtain its effect on the fit statistic (see [Budescu, 1993](https://psycnet.apa.org/doiLanding?doi=10.1037%2F1082-989X.8.2.129)).

Provides a single number to quantify the effect of the predictor across all the levels of the unordered outcome variable that are fairly straightforward to compare.  This approach appears to answer some of the questions you have about your model.

There is also several examples of how to implement in [R](https://github.com/jluchman/domir#multinomial-logistic-softmax-regression-with-extra-features) as well as [Stata](https://github.com/jluchman/domin#multinomial-logistic-regression-based-da) (though this example is a bit more complex).

Comment: Thank you! I will review accordingly!